# RegEx expression to populate option values in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, regex, dreamweaver

I have a list of options in my select box code in Dreamweaver, like this:

```
<option value="">Corby</option>
<option value="">Coventry</option>
<option value="">Craigavon</option>
<option value="">Cramlington</option>
```

I need to go through the HTML and explicitly add whatever is in each option to the value, so I want this:

```
<option value="Corby">Corby</option>
<option value="Coventry">Coventry</option>
<option value="Craigavon">Craigavon</option>
<option value="Cramlington">Cramlington</option>
```

Is there a regex that can save me the tedium of doing this manually (there are loads of cities in the UK...)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason an array would not work in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be able to `Find` this:

```
<option value="">([^<]*)</option>
```

and `Replace` it with this:

```
<option value="$1">$1</option>
```

Please let me know if there are situations where this fails

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio we use

Find what:

```
\<option value=""\>{([^\<]*)}
```

Replace with

```
<option value="\1">\1
```

Comment: Visual Studio is the funniest thing - they created a new regular expression syntax (unlike any other I have seen) even though the languages specifically designed for the IDE use a FAR MORE TRADITIONAL regex syntax... anyways, VS regex syntax is nearly useless in any other context :D

Comment: yeah, i had to actually look it up and then went "wtf"... why they couldnt just follow suit, mr bigshoes only knows

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what flavor of regex dreamweaver supports but this will work :

```
$subject =~ s!<option[^>]*>(.*?)</option>!<option value="$1">$1</option>!g;
```

This is perl by the way. If you need another version let me know ;)

Comment: I love perl where you can just specify the split character, in your case as !.. nice!